# Faster block all routes in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I try

```
var _LOCK_ = true; // or load it from config

app.all('*', function(req,res,next){
   if(_LOCK_) return res.send(401);
   next();
});

// this place other routes
app.get(...);
app.post(...);
```

This works well. But I doubt whether all right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`app.use`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) is more appropriate for a function that you want processed on every request.  It will be slightly faster since it avoids having to match the route against the request URL.

```
var _LOCK_ = true; // or load it from config

app.use(function(req,res,next){
   if(_LOCK_) return res.send(401);
   next();
});
app.use(app.router); // your middleware function must be above the router
```